# PIC16: Why are the configuration words 14 bit, but all other registers 8 bit?

Tags: pic

A PIC16 (e.g. [this one](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41391D.pdf)) have a bunch of registers, which are 8 bit wide, and two "Configuration words" (see pages 43, 44) which are 14 bit wide.

Why do the configuration words make exception for the PIC16?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The configuration words are the same width as the program flash memory.

Comment: For completeness: ...and these configuration words are mapped in program/instruction memory. They are mapped at an address location which is not accessible during normal device operation (it can be accessed only during programming mode)